# Tumblr style UserHoverCard

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

Hi everyone i have one problem with ajax hover. I am trying to make a userHoverCard like tumblr. But the hover animation not working when i use it with ajax.

This is working **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/full/xbPXwO/)** without ajax only css. In this demo you can see when you hover image then `.p-tooltip` will open with animation effect.

But if you click this **[DEMO](http://www.ecowebtr.com/test/test.php)** from my test page then you can see when you hover an image then `.p-tooltip` will not open with animation effect.

HTML

```
    <div class="p-tooltip"></div>
    <div class="summary" data-id="25">
      <a href=#" class="profile-ava"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="summary" data-id="20">
      <a href=#" class="profile-ava"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="summary" data-id="25">
      <a href=#" class="profile-ava"></a>
    </div>
```

This is my ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

        function showProfileTooltip(e, id){ 
           e.append($('.p-tooltip').css({ 
             'top':'20', 
             'left':'80' 
             }).show()); 
            //send id & get info from get_profile.php 
             $.ajax({
             url: 'get_profile.php?uid='+id,
             beforeSend: function(){

             $('.p-tooltip').html('Loading..');
             },
             success: function(html){ 
             $('.p-tooltip').html(html); 
             } 
           }); 
         } 

        function hideProfileTooltip(){ 
        $('.p-tooltip').hide().fadeIn('fast'); 
         } 
        $('.summary a').hover(function(e){ 

          var id = $(this).attr('data-id'); 
          showProfileTooltip($(this), id); 

          }, function(){ 
          setTimeout(function(){ 
          hideProfileTooltip(); 
          },2000); 
         });
    });
```

And here is CSS code:

```
.summary {
  margin: 50px auto 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}
.profile-ava {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: url(http://gravatar.com/avatar/3913c4e14034c0a7f28db2c632290c21?s=80);
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-size: 50px 50px;
  display: block;
}

.summary a:hover:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 0;
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}


.p-tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 10px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -140px;
  width: 280px;
  max-height: 120px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.profile-header {
  height: 120px;
  background-image: url(https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/571038694/1395748220/1500x500);
  background-size: auto 120px;
  background-position: 50%;
}
.profile-navigation {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.profile-nick {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.4em 0;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.profile-action {
  float: right;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 0.4em;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-weight: bold;
}


.p-tooltip .profile-ava {
  margin: -40px auto 0;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-size: 80px;
  border: 3px solid #F0F0F0;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.profile-info {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
}
.profile-title {font-size: 1.6em; margin: 0;}
.profile-description {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.profile-items {margin: 0px; padding: 10px;}
.profile-items:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.profile-items li {  
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.profile-items li:not(:first-child) {margin-left: 10px;}
.profile-items li:nth-child(1) {
  background-image: url(https://o.twimg.com/1/proxy.jpg?t=FQQVBBgwaHR0cHM6Ly9pLnl0aW1nLmNvbS92aS9CM3lna2lYRXVyWS9ocWRlZmF1bHQuanBnFAIWABIA&s=z1wybbbNHF0pyLthl3xhxVBNjbYlAEWEzPd-dUtrWOY);
}
.profile-items li:nth-child(2) {
  background-image: url(https://pbs.twimg.com/media/B7pkXfgCIAAwoY0.jpg:thumb);
}
.profile-items li:nth-child(3) {
  background-image: url(https://pbs.twimg.com/media/B7A3NHjIIAIt6eg.png:large);
}


.profile-header {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50px);
  -moz-transform: translate(0, -50px);
  transform: translate(0, -50px);

  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;

  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.1s;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;

  opacity: 0;
}
.profile-info {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 50px);
  -moz-transform: translate(0, 50px);
  transform: translate(0, 50px);

  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;

  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.1s;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
.p-tooltip .profile-ava {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.5) translate(0, -10px);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.5) translate(0, -10px);
  transform: scale(0.5) translate(0, -10px);

  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;

  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.1s;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;

  opacity: 0;
}
.profile-items li {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 50px);
  -moz-transform: translate(0, 50px);
  transform: translate(0, 50px);

  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;

  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
  opacity: 0;
}
.profile-items li:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.35s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.35s;
  transition-delay: 0.35s;
}
.profile-items li:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.4s;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0.4s;
  transition-delay: 0.4s;
}


.summary:hover .p-tooltip {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 600px;
}
.summary:hover .profile-header,
.summary:hover .profile-info,
.summary:hover .p-tooltip .profile-ava,
.summary:hover .profile-items li {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0,0) scale(1);
  -moz-transform: translate(0,0) scale(1);
  transform: translate(0,0) scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Anyone can help me please!

Comment: On hover, you're changing the CSS of the tooltip with jQuery. Don't do it. Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ka93vhe5/). Since I don't have access to your get_profile.php page, I can't help you with it's ajax call. I also deleted some unnecessary code.  Try the fiddle and see if it works.

Comment: @Preetesh.Dev ah i know this think i need to call the css. It is not working without `e.append($('.p-tooltip').css({'top':'20','left':80'}).show());`

Comment: Exactly, what is not working without `e.append`? Your question is regarding animation, which works fine if you remove that unnecessary code.

Comment: @Preetesh.Dev When you hover image then ajax call user information with id. The id is user id.  If i remove `e.append($('.p-tooltip').css({'top':'20','left':80'}).show());` then .p-tooltip now will show at the bottom of the picture.

Comment: @Preetesh.Dev i updated my question there is a `<div class="summary" data-id="25">
  <a href=#" class="profile-ava"></a>
</div>` now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, I've created a pretty clever workaround. It is a mask that covers the image (invisible) until the html is loaded, then the hover css takes place after the z-index is lowered. The hover javascript is on the container.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/sw4ev8b4/6/)

```
.summary {
    margin: -50px auto 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}
.summary-mask {
    margin: 50px auto 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.loaded .summary-mask {
    z-index: -1;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="the-container">
    <div class="summary-mask"></div>
    <div class="summary" data-id="100"> <a href="http://kraigo.tumblr.com/" class="profile-ava"></a>

        <div class="user-container"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var response = '<div class="p-tooltip"> <div class="profile-header"></div> <div class="profile-navigation"> <a href="http://kraigo.tumblr.com/" class="profile-action">Follow</a> <p class="profile-nick"> <a href="http://kraigo.tumblr.com/">Page Name</a> </p> </div> <div class="profile-ava"></div> <div class="profile-info"> <h1 class="profile-title">Username</h1> <p class="profile-description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy ..</p> </div> <ul class="profile-items"> <li></li> <li></li> <li></li> </ul> </div>';

$(document).ready(function () {

    function showProfileTooltip(e, id) {
        //send id & get info from get_profile.php 
        $.ajax({
            url: '/echo/html/',
            data: {
                html: response,
                delay: 0
            },
            method: 'post',
            success: function (returnHtml) {
                e.find('.user-container').html(returnHtml).promise().done(function () {
                    $('.the-container').addClass('loaded');
                });
            }
        });

    }

    function hideProfileTooltip() {
        $('.the-container').removeClass('loaded');
    }
    $('.the-container').hover(function (e) {

        var id = $(this).find('.summary').attr('data-id');
        showProfileTooltip($(this), id);

    }, function () {
        hideProfileTooltip();
    });
});
```

Comment: i am getting undefined error: `http://localhost:8888/get_profile.php?uid=undefined&html=%3Cdiv+class%3D%22p-tooltip%2......Fdiv%3E&delay=0` My php section has no problem. What is the problem here ?

Comment: Double check this line is correct: `var id = $(this).find('.summary').attr('data-id');` I would even change it to `var id = $(this).find('.summary').data('id');`

Comment: how can i add loading animation beforeSend ? I want to add my loading animation. This is what i want to add : [DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/wBPXPR) I still try to add this loading div but it didn't work

Comment: When i hover any image the `.ajax-loader` showing all images [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sw4ev8b4/10/)

Comment: Dear friend can you help me for this question: [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28648745/grid-system-space-right-side)

Answer (score 0):

When you are showing the card, it only contains the loading message. When the content arrives and you put it in the card, that isn't a CSS change, so the transition isn't activated.

If you wait until the content has arrives to show the card, there is something to animate.

Comment: @innovation: Put the `e.append($('.p-tooltip').css({ top:'20', left:'80' }).show());` after the `$('.p-tooltip').html(html);`.

Comment: everything is same nothing changing.

Comment: @innovation: Aha, it's also the loading message that messes up the animation. If you simply remove the loading message, then the animation works fine. Consider using a different element for the loading message, or hide the loading message before putting the loaded content in the element.