# Django get_fields but not foreignkey fields

Tags: django, django-orm

I am trying to make search for a string through all the fielsd of one table in my models. I tried to use the "._meta.fields" django trick, but it gives me back all the fields, including the Foregn Key fields. 
How can I exclude these ? And get only the "local" fields from a table ?

for example I have :

```
class Info(models.Model):
    concerning      = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name            = models.CharField(max_length=100 , blank=True)
    value           = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    creation_date   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

And I want to get : ( name , value, creation_date)

I had a look to these pages but could not find a way:

https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/new_meta_api

[Search multiple fields of django model without 3rd party app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487054/search-multiple-fields-of-django-model-without-3rd-party-app)

[Get model's fields in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647805/get-models-fields-in-django)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just check the class of the field using [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
simple_field_names = [field.name for field in Info._meta.fields
                             if field.name != 'id' and
                                not isinstance(field, models.ForeignKey)]
```

If you want to get list of text fields only then you can pass a list of required classes to `isinstance()` function:

```
text_field_names = [field.name for field in Info._meta.fields
                    if isinstance(field, (models.CharField, models.TextField))]
```

Comment: good ! can we also chek the type (charField) with this method ?

Comment: I guess we can (I am just tired :-s)

Comment: Sure you can.  I suspect that you want to check for TextFields too?  Then see the updated answer.

Comment: @catavaran Dear Can you help me my problem? [CLICK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28377882/tumblr-style-userhovercard)

Comment: @catavaran - How to sort of **mark** fields as foreignkey fields if one were to get all field names using the above method (discounting the conditions) ie. `field_names = [field.name for field in Info._meta.fields]`?