# integers and special chars in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Hi I am trying to validate text with spaces but not integers and special chars.

Here is my code

```
var pattern = /[a-zA-Z]+$/g;
return (typeof value !== 'undefined') && pattern.test(value);
```

Current results

```
abc = valid
123 invalid
abc123 invalid
a123bc valid ( it should be invalid )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pattern must be like :-

```
var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z ]+$/g;
```

Comment: @squiroid Can you help me my question ?  [CLICK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28377882/tumblr-style-userhovercard)