# Bootstrap popup when double click a table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm have a bootstrap pop up box using this code.

```
<a class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addModal"> test</a>
```

It is working without having any issue. Now I need to do the same(Appear the same pop up) when user double click on a table row which is in the same page. How can I do this?

Comment: `Element.addEventListener("dblclick" function(){ ...load bootstrap modal here...  }, false)` Where element is your table row.

Comment: @Mouser- thank you for your answer. What do you mean by "...load bootstrap modal here..." section?

Comment: Well you need to invoke the modal dialog there with code. Otherwise nothing happens when you double click on the table row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$('tr').on('dblclick', function() {
    $('#addModal').modal('show');
});
```

Since modal is already initialized by data attibutes on the button (`data-target="#addModal"`), you just need to bind `dblclick` event and show modal with [`.modal('show')`](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-methods) method.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/J0SuQdy00dcf9baE7xJu?p=preview

Comment: can you help me my question please ? [CLICK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28377882/tumblr-style-userhovercard)

Answer (score 1):

This should work :) listen to double click and after that trigger modal manualy.

```
 $('.table-row').on('dblclick', function(){
       $('#addModal').modal('show')
    });
```

Source: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Answer (score 1):

Bind double click event on table row and fire 'show' of bootstrap modal in its callback.

It should be something like --

```
$('tr').dblclick(function(){
$('#addModal').modal('show');
})
```