# Object not reflecting attribute in paragraph

Tags: javascript, object

I have written a simple code that runs properly in console, but is not reflecting the property of object in code, I cant make out whats wrong with the code:

```
<html>
<head> 
<script> 
function alpha(){
var x = {name:"Sunil",age:37,gender:"male"};
document.getElementById('para1').innerHTML(x.name);
console.log(x.name);
}
</script> 
</head> 
<body> 
<button id=but1 onclick=alpha()>Click Me</button> 
<p id=para1> This is paragraph One.  </p>
</body> 
</html>
```

Kindly, denote where am I wrong, as console is working fine with same code if I remove #para1 line from head!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to add something to @Guffa's answer, you will see that type of thing with libraries like jQuery where `.html('Hallo')` is the right thing to do, because the `html` method allows you to both set and get the value.

Answer (score 1):

`innerHTML` is not a method, it's a property. Assign the text to the property:

```
document.getElementById('para1').innerHTML = x.name;
```

Comment: can i ask you something ?

Comment: @innovation: You just did. ;)

Comment: can you check my question please ? [CLICK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28377882/tumblr-style-userhovercard)

Comment: I've never seen that happen before.